# "Descent" of analytic functions along a finite morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, analytic-functions

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of smooth affine algebraic varieties over the complex numbers. Is it true that a function on $Y$ whose pullback via $f$ is an analytic function on $X$, is itself analytic?

I ask because I am interested in knowing that, for a reductive complex algebraic group $G$, an analytic $W$-invariant function on a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ lifts to an analytic $G$-invariant function on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. So, if I am not mistaken, it is enough for me to know that an analytic function on $\mathfrak{h}$, invariant under $W$, gives rise to an analytic function on $W \backslash \mathfrak{h}$.

Thanks,
Sasha

Comment: You should at least assume that your function is continuous, otherwise there are obvious counter-examples.

Comment: @abx: I had the same initial gut reaction, but it is unnecessary: since $f$ is a finite surjection, hence topologically a quotient map, a function on $Y$ whose composition with $f$ is continuous must itself be  continuous.

Comment: @Sándor Kovács: root $\circ$ power is not identity in general, that's your mistake if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @Sasha: Right, it would just mash everything into a wedge. I knew it was too simple...

Comment: For a reference to your invariant theoretic application see my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237666/g-invariant-holomorphic-vs-polynomial-functions.

Comment: Concerning the group-theoretic motivation, why is $W\backslash\mathfrak{h}$ smooth?

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly: It is a well-known theorem that this quotient is isomorphic to an affine space. But I guess that this doesn't really matter if one knows how to work with analytic spaces well enough, your proof below will carry?

Comment: @Friedrich Knop: Thank you! Just to clarify for myself, the proof below by Moret-Bailly will work too for establishing the fact I wanted, right?

Comment: @Sasha: the result is false for general $Y$ (I'll edit my answer later); it might be true if $Y$ is normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $h:Y\to \mathbb{C}$ be such a function. If $U\subset Y$ is an open subset (for the complex topology) and $s:U\to X$ is an (analytic) local section of $f$ on $U$, then $h=h\circ f\circ s$ on $U$, hence $h_{\vert U}$ is analytic since $h\circ f$ is.

So, $h$ is analytic on  $Y\smallsetminus B$ where $B\subset Y$ is the branch locus of $f$, which is a proper Zariski closed subset. Since $h$ is continuous on $Y$ by nfdc23's remark, it follows that it is analytic on $Y$.

[EDIT] It seems plausible that the argument works assuming $Y$ normal. Here is a counterexample where it isn't: take for $Y$ the cuspidal cubic in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (with equation $y^2=x^3$ and for $f:X=\mathbb{C}\to Y$ the normalization (mapping $t$ to $(t^2,t^3)$). Then $f$ is  homeomorphism, so $t$ descends to a continuous function on $Y$, which is not analytic.

Comment: Thank you. Probably very elementary, but where can I read about this fact -
 that a continuous function on an analytic manifold, being analytic outside a proper subvariety, is analytic?

Comment: OK, references can be found here: http://planetmath.org/riemannsremovablesingularitytheoreminseveralvariables

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly .The argument works for Y normal .See Grauert Remmert Coherent Analytic Sheaves page 144. In fact Y semi-normal is enough.